# Form childs doesn't resize when form resize because of minimumsize

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a form with a SplitContainer in dock fill. In panel 1 of the split container I have buttons, in panel 2, I have a UserControl in dock fill. The Usercontrol classes in panel2 change depending on buttons clicked in panel1 but is kept dock fill.
Each Usercontrol have a minimum size.

The MinimumSize of the form is recalculate every time I change UCs and also when I move the splitter. This looks perfectly fine.

When I resize the form manually, everything follow as intended by default : fine. Meaning, the form can't be resized under minimum size value.
When I move the splitter manually, everything follow as intended by default : fine. Meaning, panel 1 and panel 2 UC resize as well as all the children.

But, when at any given moment if the form is at minimum size and I try to move the slider. The form resize properly to allow panel 2 UC minimum size to fit BUT the UC doesn't resize...

Any idea why and how to fix it?

As suggested, I simplified the application to a minimum and here is the code of the MainForm :

```vb
Public Class MainForm
  Private Sub SetMinSize()
    Dim borderWidth = Me.Width - Me.ClientSize.Width
    Me.MinimumSize = New Size(borderWidth + Me.SplitContainerMain.Panel1.Size.Width + Me.SplitContainerMain.SplitterWidth + Me.MainUserControl.MinimumSize.Width,
                              Me.MinimumSize.Height)
  End Sub

  Private Sub MainUserControl_ControlAdded(sender As Object, e As ControlEventArgs)
    Me.SetMinSize()
  End Sub

  Private Sub SplitContainerMain_SplitterMoved(sender As Object, e As SplitterEventArgs) Handles SplitContainerMain.SplitterMoved
    Me.SetMinSize()
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    Me.SplitContainerMain.Panel2.Controls.Remove(Me.MainUserControl)
    Try ' The try catch avoid error in case the handle is not created
      RemoveHandler Me.MainUserControl.ControlAdded, AddressOf Me.MainUserControl_ControlAdded
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Me.MainUserControl.Dispose()

    Me.MainUserControl = New UC1UserControl

    Me.MainUserControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Me.SplitContainerMain.Panel2.Controls.Add(Me.MainUserControl)
    AddHandler Me.MainUserControl.ControlAdded, AddressOf Me.MainUserControl_ControlAdded
    Me.ResumeLayout()

    Me.SetMinSize()
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    Me.SplitContainerMain.Panel2.Controls.Remove(Me.MainUserControl)
    Try ' The try catch avoid error in case the handle is not created
      RemoveHandler Me.MainUserControl.ControlAdded, AddressOf Me.MainUserControl_ControlAdded
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Me.MainUserControl.Dispose()

    Me.MainUserControl = New UC2UserControl

    Me.MainUserControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Me.SplitContainerMain.Panel2.Controls.Add(Me.MainUserControl)
    AddHandler Me.MainUserControl.ControlAdded, AddressOf Me.MainUserControl_ControlAdded
    Me.ResumeLayout()

    Me.SetMinSize()
  End Sub
End Class
```

And this is the designer:

```vb
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()>
Partial Class MainForm
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form remplace la méthode Dispose pour nettoyer la liste des composants.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()>
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Requise par le Concepteur Windows Form
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'REMARQUE : la procédure suivante est requise par le Concepteur Windows Form
    'Elle peut être modifiée à l'aide du Concepteur Windows Form.  
    'Ne la modifiez pas à l'aide de l'éditeur de code.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()>
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.SplitContainerMain = New System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer()
        Me.Button2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.MainUserControl = New UserControl()
    CType(Me.SplitContainerMain, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        Me.SplitContainerMain.Panel1.SuspendLayout()
        Me.SplitContainerMain.Panel2.SuspendLayout()
        Me.SplitContainerMain.SuspendLayout()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'SplitContainerMain
        '
        Me.SplitContainerMain.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
        Me.SplitContainerMain.FixedPanel = System.Windows.Forms.FixedPanel.Panel1
        Me.SplitContainerMain.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
        Me.SplitContainerMain.Name = "SplitContainerMain"
        '
        'SplitContainerMain.Panel1
        '
        Me.SplitContainerMain.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.Button2)
        Me.SplitContainerMain.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
        Me.SplitContainerMain.Panel1MinSize = 170
        '
        'SplitContainerMain.Panel2
        '
        Me.SplitContainerMain.Panel2.Controls.Add(Me.MainUserControl)
        Me.SplitContainerMain.Panel2MinSize = 0
        Me.SplitContainerMain.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(784, 561)
        Me.SplitContainerMain.SplitterDistance = 170
        Me.SplitContainerMain.TabIndex = 0
        '
        'Button2
        '
        Me.Button2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(40, 110)
        Me.Button2.Name = "Button2"
        Me.Button2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
        Me.Button2.TabIndex = 1
        Me.Button2.Text = "Button2"
        Me.Button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'Button1
        '
        Me.Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(40, 41)
        Me.Button1.Name = "Button1"
        Me.Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
        Me.Button1.TabIndex = 0
        Me.Button1.Text = "Button1"
        Me.Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'MainUserControl
        '
        Me.MainUserControl.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
        Me.MainUserControl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
        Me.MainUserControl.Name = "MainUserControl"
        Me.MainUserControl.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(610, 561)
        Me.MainUserControl.TabIndex = 0
        '
        'MainForm
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.AutoSize = True
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(784, 561)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.SplitContainerMain)
        Me.MinimumSize = New System.Drawing.Size(800, 600)
        Me.Name = "MainForm"
        Me.Tag = ""
        Me.Text = "Demo"
        Me.SplitContainerMain.Panel1.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.SplitContainerMain.Panel2.ResumeLayout(False)
        CType(Me.SplitContainerMain, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        Me.SplitContainerMain.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub

    Friend WithEvents SplitContainerMain As SplitContainer
  Friend WithEvents MainUserControl As UserControl
  Friend WithEvents Button2 As Button
    Friend WithEvents Button1 As Button
End Class
```

And Here is some screen shots :

[UC1UserControl displayed correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTJdA.png)

[UC2UserControl displayed correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIwXr.png)

[UC2UserControl after spliter moved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eddGU.png)

There is finally no code in UC1UserControl and UC2UserControl except an Label and and a different backcolor to identifiy the UC.

Thanks

Comment: There's too much going on in your code to expect someone to visualize it in their mind's eye (for me at least). It would help if you included some code - a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to the site's standards.

Comment: Perhaps before working on an example, you could log events being handled such as Resize events, as a way to debug it yourself.

Comment: I have updated my question as suggested, I hope it is now understandable.

Comment: @jérémyCourbat You might want to also include the code in your `MainForm.Designer.vb` file and/or screenshots of how the form looks like.

Comment: Yes obviously, it will help ^^

Comment: I have update the question as requested.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of testing, logging ,etc...
I have found a solution to this.

I have added a line in the sub SetMinSize :

```vb
  Private Sub SetMinSize()
    Dim borderWidth = Me.Width - Me.ClientSize.Width
    Me.MinimumSize = New Size(borderWidth + Me.SplitContainerMain.Panel1.Size.Width + Me.SplitContainerMain.SplitterWidth + Me.MainUserControl.MinimumSize.Width,
                              borderHeight + Me.MainUserControl.MinimumSize.Height)
    Me.SplitContainerMain.Panel2.Size = Me.MainUserControl.Size
  End Sub
```

And now it works. Apparently, when moving the splitter, the right panel of the SplitContainer (SplitContainerMain.Panel2) wasn't resized after the form resized.